# Haskell 'doesPathExist' Expected type: Bool, Actual type: IO Bool

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to validate a directories existence so I can add it into a list of valid directories, however I'm getting errors regarding type mismatches.

My function is here:

```
--Make a list of files to work on using a range
mkFileList :: String -> [String] -> [Int] -> [String]
mkFileList fp fps range = do
    let syear = range !! 0
    let smonth = range !! 1
    let sday = range !! 2
    let fyear = range !! 3
    let fmonth = range !! 4
    let fday = range !! 5
    if dateCheck range
      then do newp <- fp ++ "/orders/" ++ (show syear) ++ "/" ++ (show smonth) ++ "/" ++ (show sday)
              direx <- doesPathExist (show newp)

              --Check new directory exists and add if it does
              if direx
                then fps ++ newp
                else do pure ()
              --Construct new variables 
              if (sday+1) > 31
                then do sday <- return (1)
                        if (smonth+1) > 12
                          then do smonth <- return (1)
                                  syear <- return (syear+1)
                                  pure ()
                          else do smonth <- return (smonth+1)
                                  pure ()
                else do sday <- return (sday+1)
                        pure ()
              mkFileList fp fps [syear, smonth, sday, fyear, fmonth, fday]        
      else fps
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Main.hs:141:28: error:
* Couldn't match type `IO' with `[]'
  Expected type: [Bool]
    Actual type: IO Bool
* In a stmt of a 'do' block: direx <- doesPathExist (show newp)
  In the expression:
    do newp <- fp
                 ++
                   "/orders/"
                     ++ (show syear) ++ "/" ++ (show smonth) ++ "/" ++ (show sday)
       direx <- doesPathExist (show newp)
       if direx then fps ++ newp else do pure ()
       if (sday + 1) > 31 then
           do sday <- return (1)
              ....
       else
           do sday <- return (sday + 1)
              ....
       ....
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    if dateCheck range then
        do newp <- fp
                     ++
                       "/orders/"
                         ++ (show syear) ++ "/" ++ (show smonth) ++ "/" ++ (show sday)
           direx <- doesPathExist (show newp)
           if direx then fps ++ newp else do ...
           ....
    else
        fps
              direx <- doesPathExist (show newp)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

EDIT: I've changed my code a fair amount to be somewhat cleaner, still have the same error on 'direx <- doesPathExist (show newp)' however.

```
--Make a list of files to work on using a range
mkFileList :: String -> [String] -> [Int] -> [String]
mkFileList fp fps range = do
    let syear = range !! 0
    let smonth = range !! 1
    let sday = range !! 2
    let fyear = range !! 3
    let fmonth = range !! 4
    let fday = range !! 5
    if dateCheck range
      then do let newp = fp ++ "/orders/" ++ (show syear) ++ "/" ++ (show smonth) ++ "/" ++ (show sday)
              direx <- doesPathExist (show newp)

              --Check new directory exists and add if it does
              if direx
                then do fps ++ [(show newp)]
                        let nrange = plusOneDay range
                        mkFileList fp fps nrange
                else do let nrange = plusOneDay range
                        mkFileList fp fps nrange      
      else fps
```

Comment: `newp` should be defined using `let` as well, not `<-`. You are basically trying to use the list monad to nondeterministically set `newp` to a character from the path, not to the path itself.

Comment: Without looking at the rest of the code closely, I question whether *any* of the `do` blocks are appropriate. They don't appear to be.

Comment: It's not clear what `doesPathExist` does, but if - as the name suggests - it inspects the file system to get its result, then you can only use it in a function whose return type is in the `IO` monad.

Comment: Just as an aside: `fp ++ "/orders/" ++ (show syear) ++ "/" ++ (show smonth) ++ "/" ++ (show sday)` can be written a bit more tidily as `fp </> "orders" </> show syear </> show smonth </> show sday` using `</>` from the `filepath` package, which uses the platform directory separator—or more compactly as `joinPath $ fp : "orders" : map show [syear, smonth, sday]`. You can also pattern-match `let [syear, smonth, sday, fyear, fmonth, fday] = range`, but it would be better to introduce a separate data type for date ranges, rather than `[Int]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `mkFileList` can not return type `[String]` but instead must be `IO [String]` to interact with the file system.  When you make that change you'll also want to change your `else fps` to `else return fps`.

As it stands, the monad GHC infers when you type `do` is the list monad and this propagates to cause an error message that confuses you.

Comment: This was really helpful and somewhat worked, only now on 'then do fps ++ [(show newp)]' it's saying its expecting a type 'IO String' and the actual type is 'String', any thoughts?

Comment: Be sure you `return (fps ++ [(show newp)])`   Also `let newp = ...` instead of `newp <-`.

Comment: This was 100% the right answer, you sir, are a genius.